# how to post json object in apigee baas using titanium studio

Tags: json, titanium

```
var jsonobj = { "username" : "cat" };

var client=Ti.Ui.createHttpClient({
    onload:{ },
    onerror : { }   
});

client.open('POST',api.usergrid.com/serv-d/demo1/logs);
client.send(jsonobj);
```

Details:
   jsonobj is the json object to be posted in the apigee baas.
   `client.open` has the url for the apigee baas.
   `client.send`   sends the json object.

Comment: what is the problem again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send your data as JSON payload not as url encoded POST fields as it is being sent right now. You just need to set the content-type to json.

```
var client = Ti.Ui.createHttpClient({
    onload:{ },
    onerror : { }   
});

client.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'JSON');
client.open('POST',api.usergrid.com/serv-d/demo1/logs);
client.send(JSON.stringify(jsonobj));
```

Comment: but the values which i have passed in the code are not properly in the apigee baas.                                                                                                
this my code in titamiun 
                    var   uname  =   tname.value.toString();
                    var   pass     =   tsurname.value.toString();

                    var   jsonobj =  {
 
                  "username"  : ' "  ' + uname + '  "  ',
                   "password"  : ' " ' + pass + ' " ' 
  
                     };

Answer (score 0):

I think your jsonobj should be:

```
var jsonobj = {username: uname, password: pass};
```

Since `JSON.stringify()` will take care of stringify-ing it.

Comment: i have tried this option also but i does not work. Apigee baas does not accept this format of object. No value gets inserted in the baas.

Comment: What value does it need then?

Comment: it needs to send the values using quotes...eg var obj = {"username" : "uname",}

Comment: it needs to send the values using quotes..  
eg var obj = {"username" : "uname",
 "password" : "pass"};

i am trying to send this values but blank values are getting passed.

Comment: But that's exactly what `JSON.stringify` will do for you.  it will add those quotes as the above requestb.in also showed. If you add them and then do JSON.stringify you get them double.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some testing with:

```
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
client.open('POST', 'http://requestb.in/1b1yblv1');
client.send(payload);
```

With:

```
var payload = {username: "cat"};
```

At http://requestb.in/1b1yblv1?inspect you see:

```
username=cat
```

With:

```
var payload = JSON.stringify({username: "cat"});
```

It is:

```
{"username":"cat"}
```

So that's what you need right?

Comment: sry i tried this solution still not working.
 thanks